# Smalltalk gst command overwritten

Tags: command-line, git

Having installed `GNU-smalltalk` through `aptitude`.

I found the that typing

```
$ gst
```

Issues a  command to `git`, any workaround for this?

Comment: What does `type -a gst` show you?

Comment: gst is an alias for git status ; gst is /usr/bin/gst

Comment: just removed the alias

Comment: I guess you can write an answer to your own question :)